# multiple row entry in phpmyadmin using for loop

Tags: php

I want to enter 100 rows generated from for loop in one instruction. 
I am using the below but its not working.

```
for($i=$roll_number_start; $i<=$roll_number_end; $i++)
                {
                    $roll_number = $roll_number_format.$i;
                    $p_username = generatePassword();
                    $p_password = generatePassword();
                    $roll_array[] = " ('".$roll_number."',"."'".$student_class."',"."'".$class_section."',"."'".$batch_year."',"."'".$p_username."',"."'".$p_password."')";

                }

                $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO student (roll_number, student_class, class_section, batch_year, p_username, p_password) VALUES".$roll_array;
```

Can u suggest me how to insert in mysql using one instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `$roll_array[]` and make it a string as follow:

```
$roll_string = '';
for($i=$roll_number_start; $i<=$roll_number_end; $i++)
{
  $roll_number = $roll_number_format.$i;
  $p_username = generatePassword();
  $p_password = generatePassword();
  $roll_string .= "('".$roll_number."',"."'".$student_class."',"."'".$class_section."',"."'".$batch_year."',"."'".$p_username."',"."'".$p_password."'),"
}
$roll_string = substr($roll_string, 0, -1);
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO student (roll_number, student_class, class_section, batch_year, p_username, p_password) VALUES ".$roll_string;
```

Comment: its working fine thanks, but can you tell me why you have taken $roll_string = ''; and dot after $roll_string .

Comment: @user2538155: first of all, you have to declare your variable (so initialize $roll_string as a empty string; in that way you can concatenate (dot symbol) other strings to it). Second, outside for loop, you have to remove last character (",") because otherwise it will not be "sql correct command".

Comment: thans dear for ur time

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3); -- use 100 times
```

or

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9).....; -- 100 () here
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array contains well-formed sets of values for insertion into the DB, you simply need to concatenate each item in the array into a single string.  `implode` does this:

```
$roll_string = implode( ',',$roll_array );
```

So, if `$roll_array` contained:

```
[
    "('a','b','c')"
   ,"('d','e','f')"
   ,"('h','i','j')"
]
```

Then `$roll_string` would now contain

```
 "('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),('h','i','j')"
```

Which you can append to a query like so

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO table_name( col1,col2,col3 )
VALUES $roll_string"
```